# Types of Coffee and Headaches?

Tags: headache, caffeine, drinks, coffee, rebound-headache

I love my coffee.

Though, when I have it, I get a headache. This was quite disappointing so I stopped drinking it.

Without thinking, I recently (a couple of months since stopped drinking) bought some instant coffee as I had a craving for it. Surprisingly it didn't give me a headache, and it was not until I bought a coffee when I was out did I get a headache.

So, I think it must be coffee made from coffee machines (aka Expresso Machine/Manual) that trigger them.

I am just wondering if anyone knows why this is happening or advice if this happens to you.

Comment: Interesting. I get headaches when I quit my coffee :)

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Just for clarification, has the instant coffee you bought been decaf coffee by any chance?

Comment: @Lucky I don't believe so. Could caffeine be triggering it?

Comment: I don't have time to do sufficient research for a proper answer at the moment, but I'll try to explain without answering in comments (because that's not allowed here): I wasn't referring to caffeine causing headaches directly, but since it can affect the diameter of blood vessels in the brain and cerebral blood flow and it might affect blood pressure, I thought that weather the coffee had caffeine might be a relevant piece of information for your question. It is not necessarily relevant,  but it might be, and the more details we have, the better.